# Using sessions on Passportjs conditionally (depending on strategy)?

Tags: node.js, session, passport.js

I have an express app that serves both users and api-clients (renders html for the first and json for the second)

So I use both Local Strategy (for human users) and Basic Strategy (for api-clients).

For local strategy, I need to manage user sessions. For Basic Strategy (used by api-clients), there is no need for sessions.

How do I tell passportjs not to use/create a session if a request was authenticated using Basic Strategy ?

Comment: this issue might help https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/179